# How to convert Android Swipe to Android TouchAction?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, appium

I was using AppiumStudio tool to run some tests on an Android Applicative that I've created.
The tool auto generates a Java Code and I took that code to test on Eclipse. But when I pasted the code, Java doesn't recognize driver.swipe(); even with all imports done.
Here is the code that the tool generated

```
package Appium;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.junit.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class Cadastro_base {
 private String reportDirectory = "reports";
 private String reportFormat = "xml";
 private String testName = "Cadastro_base";
 protected AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = null;

 DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

 @Before
 public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
  dc.setCapability("reportDirectory", reportDirectory);
  dc.setCapability("reportFormat", reportFormat);
  dc.setCapability("testName", testName);
  dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "5210ce98fa7eb4b3");
  driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
 }

 @Test
 public void testCadastro_base() {
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='emailView']")).sendKeys("teduspwrpbrasil@mailinator.com");
  driver.swipe(500, 596, 518, 478, 471);
  driver.swipe(434, 468, 471, 312, 417);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password_view']")).sendKeys("Smart2000");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='confirm_password_view']")));
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='confirm_password_view']")).sendKeys("Smart2000");
  driver.swipe(734, 368, 737, 212, 813);
  driver.swipe(290, 987, 346, 571, 2003);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='name_and_surname_view']")).sendKeys("TED USP");
  driver.swipe(409, 518, 493, 256, 1468);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='cpfView']")).sendKeys("41801452865");
  driver.swipe(531, 465, 637, 175, 1724);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dobView']")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='OK']")).click();
  driver.swipe(650, 481, 756, 215, 1627);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='phoneView']")).sendKeys("13982133161");
  driver.swipe(446, 800, 468, 675, 1359);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='generView']")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Feminino']")).click();
  driver.swipe(584, 712, 590, 609, 1013);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Cadastrar']")).click();
 }

 @After
 public void tearDown() {
     driver.quit();
 }
}
```

My question is: To run the test correctly I need to Swipe between fields on the screen. How can I convert the command driver.swipe to a TouchAction or a working command that will do the touch and move action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use TouchAction (https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html)

Using current deprecated methods in java client 6 beta:

```
new TouchAction(driver).press(startX, startY).waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration)).moveTo(endX, endY).release().perform();
```

Using new methods:

```
new TouchAction(localdriver).press(point(startX, startY)).waitAction(waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(duration)))
            .moveTo(point(endX, endY)).release().perform();
```

startX, startY, endX, endY are your coordinates
duration is time of swipe in milliseconds (try 1000)

Comment: I tried using new TouchAction(driver).longPress(1046,1221).moveTo(1046,1504).perform().release(); But it doesn't do the action and most of TouchAction methods are deprecated :/

Comment: On Duration.ofMillis(1000) I'm recieving this: The method ofMillis(int, null) is undefined for the type Duration

Comment: its import java.time.Duration;

Comment: I did everything as you said me. The code doesn't show any error, but when I run the code it fails and shows this exception:
The source attachment does not contain the source for the file TouchAction.class

Comment: You don't have the proper java-client library or not loading it correctly on classpath. Try to use maven for instance to manage dependencies for you.